# magento rest api | access denied

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have this structure

[image]

in POSTMAN i send 
[image]

api2.xml i have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <custom_restapi translate="title" module="Custom_Restapi">
            <title>Custom Rest API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </custom_restapi>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <custom_restapi translate="title" module="Custom_Restapi">
            <group>custom_restapi</group>
            <model>custom_restapi/api2_restapi</model>
            <title>Testing My Rest API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <create>1</create>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes  translate="" module="Custom_Restapi">
                <firstname>First Name</firstname>
                <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
                <email>Email</email>
                <password>Password</password>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_entity>
                    <route>/customer/create</route>
                    <action_type>entity</action_type>
                </route_entity>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/customer/create</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </custom_restapi>
    </resources>
</api2>
```

how do i get access? What do I need to do?